# Python app in Docker container doesn't stop/remove Docker container when app fails

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I've got a Python application that polls a queue for new data, and inserts it into a TimescaleDB database (TimescaleDB is an extension for PostgreSQL). **This application *must* stay running at all times.**

The problem is, the Python program may fail from time to time, and I expect Docker Swarm to restart the container. However, the containers keep running even after failure. **Why aren't my containers failing and then being restarted by Docker Swarm?**

The Python app looks something like this:

```py
def main():
    try:
        conn = get_db_conn()
        insert_data(conn)
    except Exception:
        logger.exception("Error with main inserter.py function")
        send_email_if_error()
        raise
    finally:
        try:
            conn.close()
            del conn
        except Exception:
            pass

        return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

# Configure apt and install packages
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install cron nano procps

# Install Python requirements.
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip && \
    pip3 install poetry==1.0.10

COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml /
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false && \
  poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi

# Copy everything to the / folder inside the container
COPY . /

# Make /var/log the default directory in the container
WORKDIR /var/log

# Start Python app on container startup
CMD ["python3", "/inserter/inserter.py"]
```

Docker-Compose file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  inserter13:
    # Name and tag of image the Dockerfile creates
    image: mccarthysean/ijack:timescale
    depends_on: 
      - timescale13
    env_file: .env
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_HOST: timescale13
    networks:
      - traefik-public
    deploy:
      # Either global (exactly one container per physical node) or
      # replicated (a specified number of containers). The default is replicated
      mode: replicated
      # For stateless applications using "replicated" mode,
      # the total number of replicas to create
      replicas: 2
      restart_policy:
        on-failure # default is 'any'

  timescale13:
    image: timescale/timescaledb:2.3.0-pg13
    volumes: 
      - type: volume
        source: ijack-timescale-db-pg13
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/data # the location in the container where the data are stored
        read_only: false
      # Custom postgresql.conf file will be mounted (see command: as well)
      - type: bind
        source: ./postgresql_custom.conf
        target: /postgresql_custom.conf
        read_only: false
    env_file: .env
    command: ["-c", "config_file=/postgresql_custom.conf"]
    ports:
      - 0.0.0.0:5432:5432
    networks:
      traefik-public:
    deploy:
      # Either global (exactly one container per physical node) or
      # replicated (a specified number of containers). The default is replicated
      mode: replicated
      # For stateless applications using "replicated" mode,
      # the total number of replicas to create
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          # Since this is for the stateful database,
          # only run it on the swarm manager, not on workers
          - "node.role==manager"
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure # default is 'any'


# Use a named external volume to persist our data
volumes:
  ijack-timescale-db-pg13:
    external: true

networks:
  # Use the previously created public network "traefik-public", shared with other
  # services that need to be publicly available via this Traefik
  traefik-public:
    external: true
```

The "Docker-compose.build.yml" file I use for building the "inserter.py" container's image:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  inserter:
    # Name and tag of image the Dockerfile creates
    image: mccarthysean/ijack:timescale
    build:
      # context: where should docker-compose look for the Dockerfile?
      # i.e. either a path to a directory containing a Dockerfile, or a url to a git repository
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.inserter
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_HOST: timescale
```

Bash script I run, which builds, pushes, and deploys the database and the inserter containers with Docker Swarm:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Build and tag image locally in one step. 
# No need for docker tag <image> mccarthysean/ijack:<tag>
echo ""
echo "Building the image locally..."
echo "docker-compose -f docker-compose.build.yml build"
docker-compose -f docker-compose.build.yml build

# Push to Docker Hub
# docker login --username=mccarthysean
echo ""
echo "Pushing the image to Docker Hub..."
echo "docker push mccarthysean/ijack:timescale"
docker push mccarthysean/ijack:timescale

# Deploy to the Docker swarm and send login credentials 
# to other nodes in the swarm with "--with-registry-auth"
echo ""
echo "Deploying to the Docker swarm..."
echo "docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth -c docker-compose.prod13.yml timescale13"
docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth -c docker-compose.prod13.yml timescale13
```

When the Python inserter program fails (could be a database connection issue, or something else), it sends me an email alert and then raises the error and fails. At this point, I expect the Docker container to fail and be restarted with Docker Swarm's `restart_policy: on-failure`. However, after an error, when I type `docker service ls` I see the following `0/2 replicas`:

```
ID                  NAME                                        MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                                         PORTS
u354h0uj4ug6        timescale13_inserter13                      replicated          0/2                 mccarthysean/ijack:timescale
o0rbfx5n2z4h        timescale13_timescale13                     replicated          1/1                 timescale/timescaledb:2.3.0-pg13              *:5432->5432/tcp
```

When it's healthy (most of the time), it shows `2/2` replicas. Why aren't my containers failing and then being restarted by Docker Swarm?

Comment: Could you try to replace CMD by ENTRYPOINT in your Dockerfile please ?

Comment: @edijon I made a fake Python app to run alongside, and used `ENTRYPOINT` instead of `CMD` in the Dockerfile. It didn't make a difference. Actually, my fake Python program keeps restarting over and over, as desired, whether I use `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`... I can't seem to replicate my previous failures to restart (i.e. `replicas 0/2`), even though it happened twice over the past month...

Comment: I suggested ENTRYPOINT to be sure that docker monitor the true PID of your process. Another check would be to test that this script ends with a non zero exit status. Another one would be to start a shell in your container ans then check your script PID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, and updated my question to provide more details on my `try: except:` failure routine.

Here was the error that happened (actually two errors in sequence, as you'll see):

```
Here's the error information: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/inserter/inserter.py", line 357, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, values)
psycopg2.errors.AdminShutdown: terminating connection due to administrator command SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/inserter/inserter.py", line 911, in main
    insert_alarm_log_rds(
  File "/inserter/inserter.py", line 620, in insert_alarm_log_rds
    rc = execute_sql(
  File "/inserter/inserter.py", line 364, in execute_sql
    conn.rollback()
psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed
```

As you can see, there was first a `psycopg2.errors.AdminShutdown` error, which was ***raised*** in my first `try: except:` routine. However, this was followed by a ***second*** `psycopg2.InterfaceError` that actually occurred in my `finally:` cleanup code, followed by a `pass` statement and a `return 0`, so the earlier error was not re-raised, I guess, and the code ended with an error code of 0 instead of ***non-zero*** which was needed to stimulate the restart.

@edijon's comment about needing a non-zero exit code was what helped me to figure this out.

I needed to re-raise the error in the `finally:` routine, as follows:

```
def main():
    try:
        conn = get_db_conn()
        insert_data(conn)
    except Exception:
        logger.exception("Error with main inserter.py function")
        send_email_if_error()
        raise
    finally:
        try:
            conn.close()
            del conn
        except Exception:
            # previously the following was just 'pass' 
            # and I changed it to 'raise' to ensure errors
            # cause a non-zero error code for Docker's 'restart_policy'
            raise

        # The following was previously "return 0"
        # which caused the container not to restart...
        # Either comment it out, or change it to return non-zero
        return 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```